# How to drag and drop elements in containers and sort using ng2-dnd (github library)

Tags: angular

im using this library that enable you to do drag and drop, and in this demo

https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd#10-simple-sortable-with-drop-into-something-without-delete-it

at the bottom there is an example of doing drag and drop in containers and sort them:

10. Simple sortable With Drop into something, without delete it

this is what im trying to do and i dont know how and the example #10 in the github page claims to do that but when I run it on plunker i cant do that...

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-sortable-copy',
    template: `
<h4>Simple sortable With Drop into something, without delete it</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-warning"
            dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="sourceList" [dropZones]="['source-dropZone']">
            <div class="panel-heading">Source List</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li *ngFor="let source of sourceList; let x = index" class="list-group-item"
                        dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="x" [dragEnabled]="true"
                        [dragData]="source">{{source.name}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Target List</div>
            <div class="panel-body" dnd-droppable (onDropSuccess)="addTo($event)" [dropZones]="['source-dropZone']">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li *ngFor="let target of targetList" class="list-group-item">
                        {{target.name}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
})
export class SimpleSortableCopyComponent {

    sourceList: Widget[] = [
        new Widget('1'), new Widget('2'),
        new Widget('3'), new Widget('4'),
        new Widget('5'), new Widget('6')
    ];

    targetList: Widget[] = [];
    addTo($event: any) {
        this.targetList.push($event.dragData);
    }
}

class Widget {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}
```

if someone can help me understand or give a small example for how to do drag and drop between containers with containers that have object inside of them that are also draggble it will be amazing!

Comment: Help is coming soon, please wait....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the GitHub readme file was out of date and have found the solution that works:

```
 <h4>Multi list sortable</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            Available boxers
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listBoxers">
            <ul class="list-group" >
              <li *ngFor="let item of listBoxers; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            First Team
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listTeamOne">
            <ul class="list-group" >
              <li *ngFor="let item of listTeamOne; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            Second Team
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listTeamTwo">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li *ngFor="let item of listTeamTwo; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here it is on plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/JbG8Si